PhpStorm Xdebug in docker container
On Linux Mint 22 I have installed Docker version 27.1.1. I try configure for using Xdebug 3 in docker container. On docker-compose.yaml I have
php:
    build:
      dockerfile: .docker/php/Dockerfile
      args:
        USER_ID: '${WWWUSER:-1000}'
        GROUP_ID: '${WWWGROUP:-1000}'
        USER: '${USER:-whoami}'
    working_dir: /var/www/project
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    vim \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libfreetype-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql intl

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=develop,debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.discover_client_host=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \

WORKDIR /var/www/project

But in docker container I have the following error and Xdebug does not debug:

NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).


"Tried: localhost:9003" If it's docker, then you need Xdebug to connect to the host OS and not inside the container (which localhost is). Have this in your php.ini: xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal -- any better?
